# htaccess: block specific IPs, then allow only partial site access

Tags: .htaccess

I manage a website and I have a list of banned IPs, like this:

```
order allow,deny
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
deny from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
etc...
allow from all
```

So far so good.

Now, it has been decided that only some specific files&folders should be public,
and ALL the rest should be private.

What I did is as follows: at the bottom of the banned IPs list, I added this in 
order to block everything:

```
Order allow,deny
deny from All
```

Then, in order to allow acces to the public stuff I added:

```
<FilesMatch foo.html>
order deny,allow
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch bar.jpg>
order deny,allow
</FilesMatch>
```

AND, inside the folders that need public access, I added a specific htacces like this:

```
satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

BUT the problem now is that the banned IPs by the root htacces have access to 
these public files, whereas we would like to have them banned from everything.

Answer (score 0):

Combining IP-specific `Deny`s with `Deny from all` does not make sense – the latter encompasses every specific one already.

You will have to set `Deny from all` for your non-public files and folders specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have the issue regarding the public files (foo.html & bar.jpg cited above), I want those to be public but NOT accessible by the banned IPs. As it is now, they are accessible by the banned IPs.

Comment: That’s because you are using the wrong [`order`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order): _“`Deny, Allow`: First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied unless it also matches an Allow directive.”_ – so your IP `Deny`s are evaluated, but then after that `Allow from all` say, _“ah, never mind – come in anyway …”_

Comment: Ok, but the single files do not have `allow from all`, they only have `<FilesMatch foo.html>
order deny,allow
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: That’s why I said you will have to do it the other way around …

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier using mod_rewrite rules. Consider this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ban all the IP addresses you want here
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx|yyy\.yyy\.yyy\.yyy)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# ban all except few allowed files/folders here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(foo\.html|bar\.jpg|folder1/|folder2/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This should be placed in root .htaccess and make sure to remove all other .htaccess from sub folders.